# Relation between surface tension to mixture of liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I found it really intresting to read about the surface tension phenomena, and I was thinking about that if there is any relation between the percent of  of liquids in a mixture. I mean if I know that $\gamma_1= A$ and $\gamma_2 = B$  (while $1$ and $2$ are some liquids) so $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ is  the values of $100$% $1$ and $100$% $2$ and I know that $\gamma_{mixture}= C$ .

Am I able to know what is the percent of $1$ and $2$ in the mixture?

I hope my question is clear enough

Comment: If you know the interaction parameters, yes you can. Is it an ideal, regular, or complex solution? All in the free energies of the mixtures.

Comment: I am talking about simple scenerio, can you show me how I can derive the relation or where it appears on the internet

Comment: Some overview might be found in https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0364591615002461?token=4E3695F526E71B0E38D2F422BCF81B1A47EB24E2933A9AB799EDF56499149435A2EB819A640DA19A538CE13BDA69FB46

Comment: is it cost money to access the article?

Comment: That may depend on your institution (if you have one). Try https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0364591615002461 or the Calphad website.

Comment: still not working.